# Why are breakpoints not working in TestComplete?

Tags: automated-tests, breakpoints, testcomplete

I'm using a trial version of TestComplete 8.70.720.7 for test automation. I've faced a problem with breakpoints - they don't work even if test debugging is turned on. What can be the reason of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestComplete uses the Microsoft Script Debugger to debug JScript and VBScript scripts. So, this functionality depends on the MS script debugging components installed on your computer. If the break points are not working, there is something wrong with the script debugging components - TestComplete can't use them for some reason. There are multiple reasons for this problem to occur. Many of them are described in the following FAQ entry in the SmartBear Support Portal:

http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/8874/

If the suggestions from that article do not help, this may mean that you have faced a situation when TestComplete is trying to use the Script Debugger installed with Visual Studio. At that, not all versions of the VS Script Debugger are compatible with TestComplete. So, if you have VS installed on your PC, try doing the following:

1. Close Visual Studio and TestComplete.
2. Rename the VS7Debug folder on your disk (the path to it looks like this: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared), to something else like "_VS7Debug".
3. Reinstall the Microsoft Script Debugger using the link from the FAQ article above. When installing under Windows 7, Vista, or Win Server 2008, run the installation with elevated permissions (use the "Run As Administrator" context menu command).

Does this fix the problem?

Comment: In TestComplete 9, which has been recently released, this problem should not appear anymore - the new version is supposed to use its own script debugger, not the one installed in the system. This is mentioned in the "Debugging Tests - Overview" topic ( http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/29595/ ) : "The keyword-test and script debugging functionality is built into TestComplete and does not have any special requirements."   So, the life is getting easier :)